# How to create add to home screen on Amp?

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, amp-html

I made a PWA with the ability to add the site as a desktop application.
How do I add this to the amp version of the site? It's use javacript and I'm not sure that it is possible.
Thanks!

Comment: read here: https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/learn/combine-amp-pwa/?format=websites

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean [service worker](https://amp.dev/documentation/examples/components/amp-install-serviceworker/) for Amp ?